# Еrror C2230 Visual C++ .NET 2003, неуправляемый тип данных (non-managed)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку:

error C2230: 'GenerateRandomHReal' : a member function of a managed class cannot return a non-managed class or struct 'HReal' unless it is an aggregate

Пишу проект на базе Windows Form Application .NET в Microsoft Visual C++ .NET 2003. Логика программы реализуется прямо в файле класса формы Form1.h (я понимаю, не очень правильно, но это детали). Программа по нажатию кнопки заполняет матрицы случайными числами и выполняет некие расчеты. Есть сторонняя математическая библиотека, написанная на неуправляемом (non-managed) С++. В этой библиотеке описан тип данных (повышенной точности) HReal. Получается, что как бы в управляемом С++ (__gc class Form1) используется функция-метод, которая принимает аргументы и возвращает значение неуправляемого типа HReal. Вот и выдается такая ошибка. Но как ее исправить?

Я читала, наткнулась на такие понятия, как: 1) шаблонный класс gcroot <ТИП>, структура GCHandle; 2) написание Wrappera для класса; 3) использование директив # pragma managed и # pragma unmanaged для совмещения в одном модуле управляемого и неуправляемого С++.

Подскажите, как исправить, может быть, используя приведенные выше понятия? Или я ищу в неправильном направлении? Подскажите, пожалуйста! Спасибо!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstringt.h>
#include <afxwin.h>

#using <mscorlib.dll>

#pragma once

namespace SolveSLAU
{
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

public __gc class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

    // Глобальные переменные
private:  bool IsButton1Pressed;
          bool IsMatrixSet; // Флаг: "Матрица уже инициализирована?"
          HReal **A01, **A02, *B01, *B02, *X1_2, *X2_1;

          double Eps; // Точность расчетов Эпсилон
          int m1, m2, n0;
          int MantissPrecision; // Точность мантиссы

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object *  sender, System::EventArgs *  e)
     {

        int n = 0, i,j;
        HReal ** A1, ** A2, *X1;
        HReal * B1, * B2, *X2;
        HReal alfa_0, alfa_1;
        CString myStr1(""); 
        CString myStr2("");
        CString myStr3("");
        CString myStr0("");
        CString myspace(" ");

        MantissPrecision = System::Int32::Parse(this->textBox1->Text);

        Eps = System::Double::Parse(this->textBox2->Text);

*****
                this->listBox6->Items->Add(System::Convert::ToString(myStr0));

                X1[i] = GenerateRandomHReal(alfa_0, alfa_1, MantissPrecision);
                X1_2[i] = GenerateRandomHReal(alfa_0, alfa_1, MantissPrecision);
                myStr0.Format(_T("%lf\n"), X1[i] );
                this->listBox2->Items->Add(System::Convert::ToString(myStr0));

                X2[i] = GenerateRandomHReal(alfa_0, alfa_1, MantissPrecision);
                X2_1[i] = GenerateRandomHReal(alfa_0, alfa_1, MantissPrecision);
                myStr0.Format(_T("%lf\n"), X2[i] );
                this->listBox5->Items->Add(System::Convert::ToString(myStr0));
            }
               }
        else 
        {

// -------------------- генератор ----------------
private: gcroot<HReal> GenerateRandomHReal(const gcroot<HReal> &a, const gcroot<HReal> &b, int MantissPrecision) // [a,b] - диапазон
{
CString s = "0.", s1;
int j;
for (int i = 0; i < MantissPrecision; i++)
{
    j = rand() % 10;
    s1.Format("%i", j);
    s += s1;
}
HReal result(s);
return a + result * (b - a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой путь — сделайте `GenerateRandomHReal` отдельной функцией, то есть вынесите её из класса `Form1`. Не забудьте, что она должна быть видима в точке, где вы её используете, поэтому объявите её *до* начала класса.

А вообще, вы пишете на C++/CLI, который совершенно ужасен. Не удивительно, что у вас с ним проблемы. Если вам нужно UI, переходите на C#, он **намного** проще, чем C++, и обо всех ужасах наподобие `gcroot` вы сможете забыть. Или наоборот пишите на чистом C++, неуправляемом, консольные приложения.

C++/CLI предназначен лишь того, чтобы писать на нём простые маленькие обёртки для нативных функций, чтобы с ними было легко работать из-под C#.